# How to convert JSON Object to Byte Array in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, file, appcelerator-titanium

I am working on Titanium or Appcelerator, and want to convert JSON object to byte Array.

As I am using SQLite and I have large amount of data(JSON object) which takes a lot of time to process in SQL queries, and takes much time to prepare a JSON Object. Now I decided to store my Data in file after converting it to byte array. I am unable to find a good method to convert it into byte array.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: I just want to convert JSON to byte array. I cannot specify my json here. because it is too large.

Comment: Hi, do you have an API you're retrieving data from? This may not be the best approach to parsing and saving data if I understand this correctly. I would take advantage of the fact you're using JSON. If you're using an API, I would personally dynamically create a DB schema in JSON format and use it to build and manage the database. Then when you go to parse and save your data, use the DB schema to create your SQL queries dynamically so you're not stuck writing queries. Or you can use a library built into titanium: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Alloy+Sync+Adapters+and+Migrations

Comment: Yes, I have an API from which I receive data in XML form. And after parsing that XML. I put my data in SQLite. But now I am thinking that parsed data should be placed in file in the form of byte array (Because SQLite is taking lot of time gathering data from different tables to make an Object). My application works online as well as offline. So I need to store data locally.